# Class Implementation Best-practice?

Tags: java, android, oop

I have a code(`Activity.class`) in which I am calling my basic method to execute.
Now I am defining another class `MyTask extending AsyncTask`.
My question is :

a) In some cases we declare external class in same java file for Example here `Activity.java` but outside the Activity class and

b) In some cases we declare external class in same java file for Example here `Activity.java` but inside the Activity class and

c)In some cases we declare external class in different java file for Example here `MyTask.java`

What is the difference between these 3 implementation with respect to accessibility, memory , and best practices.
A descriptive answer will clear my concept and is welcomed here.

Answer (score 0):

It matters on where you plan to implement the AsyncTask.

If the AsyncTask is directly related the Activity's objective, for example when you are trying to retrieve a variable from the class, then it is recommended to have the AsyncTask class within the activiy. This happens rarely however. Here you would have to refer to the AsyncTask as `ActivityName.AsyncTaskName`, so it isn't advised if the asynctask is closely related to the acivity's function

The disadvantage/advantage(depends on usage circumstances) of placing the AsyncTask in the same file but outside the activity is it can only be package-private, meaning i can only be accessed from the same package.

If you plan to be using this AsyncTask in many activities/classes, you should probably put it in a different java file

Answer (score 0):

**Accessibility or Scope**

In terms of scope, in **first case** we defining multiple java classes(not nested classes) in single files.

Java allow us to define multiple classes within a single file but with one restriction, only one class can be public.
so only one class can be accessed outside of it's package and all other will be package private classes. However after compilation every class will be represented by its own `.class` file, same as defining different files.

In **second case** we defining java class(`MyTask.java`) inside a java class(`Activity.java`),this known as inner classes(nested class in our case).

A nested class accessibility also work same as a method of class. it can be accessed outside of it's package if the class is public, via object of its enclosing class.However if we want to access the methods of nested class then we need to create object of this class too same as enclosing class.
for example `new Activity().new MyTask().foo()`

In **third case** we defining each class  as a separate files

accessibility will directly depend on what access modifier we defined for class, if class is public then it can be accessed everywhere in whole project. this way provide you the complete control over how you want your class to access.

**Memory**

In terms of **memory**, there is no difference at all

A class not have any memory until an object of class created. so it's completely irrelevant where you defined your class. memory will depends on number of objects created.

However in case of nested class if we accessing nested class outside of its enclosing class then we first going to need the object of  its enclosing class so the enclosing class will get memory even if we just want to access nested class.

but if we accessing inside then in all cases according rule memory will remain the same

**Best Practices**

in these cases best practices completely depends on use-case

for **first case** let's assume we have two `class A` and `class B` and `class A extends B` now if we know that we never going to use `class B` directly outside it's package then we can define both class in same file(not nested class) and can make `class A` as our public class

using this way we just saved a file and also time of creating a file but we also compromised the readability. in my personal opinion i will make a new file so i can easily read and check my class.

in **second case** if we know that a class is only going to used one time like `MyTask.java` will be just used in `Activity.java` then we can define it inside `Acitivty.java` using this approach we will have the all code at one place that working together for a functionality.

our **third case** can be used in so many cases and generally the most used way. each class in a separate file so later each class can be easily accessed

for our example if we know that `MyTask.java` can be used by more than one class then we can create it as a separate file with public access.